# List of Places using Platform SDK

Tags: java, genesys

### Background

My application connects to the Genesys Interaction Server in order to receive events for actions performed on the *Interaction Workspace*. I am using the Platform SDK 8.5 for Java.

I make the connection to the Interaction Server using the method described in the API reference.

```
 InteractionServerProtocol interactionServerProtocol =
         new InteractionServerProtocol(
             new Endpoint(
                   endpointName,
                   interactionServerHost,
                   interactionServerPort));
   interactionServerProtocol.setClientType(InteractionClient.AgentApplication);
   interactionServerProtocol.open();
```

Next, I need to register a listener for each Place I wish to receive events for.

```
RequestStartPlaceAgentStateReporting requestStartPlaceAgentStateReporting = RequestStartPlaceAgentStateReporting.create();
requestStartPlaceAgentStateReporting.setPlaceId("PlaceOfGold");
requestStartPlaceAgentStateReporting.setTenantId(101);
isProtocol.send(requestStartPlaceAgentStateReporting);
```

The way it is now, my application requires the user to manually specify each Place he wishes to observe. This requires him to know the names of all the Places, which he may not necessarily have [easy] access to.

### Question

How do I programmatically obtain a list of Places available? Preferably from the Interaction Server to limit the number of connections needed.

Answer (score 2):

There is a method you can use. If you check methods of applicationblocks you will see cfg and query objects. You can use it for get list of all DNs. When building query, try blank DBID,name and number.

there is a .net code similar to java code(actually exatly the same)

```
     List<CfgDN> list = new List<CfgDN>();
                List<DN> dnlist = new List<Dn>();

                CfgDNQuery query = new CfgDNQuery(m_ConfService);
                list = m_ConfService.RetrieveMultipleObjects<CfgDN>(query).ToList();
                foreach (CfgDN item in list)
                {
                  foo = (DN) item.DBID;
......

                    dnlist.Add(foo);
                }
```

Note : DN is my class which contains some property from platform SDK.

Answer (score 0):

```
KeyValueCollection tenantList = new KeyValueCollection();
tenantList.addString("tenant", "Resources");
RequestStartPlaceAgentStateReportingAll all = RequestStartPlaceAgentStateReportingAll.create(tenantList);
interactionServerProtocol.send(all);
```